# Define Data Type From an inner private class

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
interface STD{
  public Name getName();
}

class Student implements STD{
  Name getName(){ }

  private class Name{

   }
}
```

In the code above the interface can't see the private class Name, is there a way to make it see it while it's a private inner class to define a data type from it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Making private classes available through non-private methods is not a good idea in general....

Comment: It's a problem that has been presented to me and I'm trying to solve it ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected class Name
```

Use a protected variable so the interface can see it, but not any other class that isn't directly related

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that. `private` is meant to be.. private.

What you probably want to do is declaring `Name` outside `Student` (it make sense, `Name` entity shouldn't be tied only to students):

```
public class Student implements STD {
    public Name getName() { 
        // ...
    }
}

interface STD {
    public Name getName();
}

class Name { }
```

Note that you can have `Name` in a separate file, it's up to you and your needs where to place it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes I'm aware but it's just an example as I want to define a data type from a private inner class but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: @Trickster Then declare a `class Name` *inside* the interface. Making it `private` make no sense, you can't use it outside the scope.

Comment: that would solve this indeed but I'm looking for a way to define a data type from it in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
interface STD{
  public Object getName();
}


class Student implements STD {

    @Override
    public Name getName() {
        return null;
    }

    private class Name {

        private int myField = 5;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Student outer = new Student();

            // List all available constructors.
            // We must use the method getDeclaredConstructors() instead
            // of getConstructors() to get also private constructors.
            for (Constructor<?> ctor : Student.Name.class
                    .getDeclaredConstructors()) {
                System.out.println(ctor);
            }

            // Try to get the constructor with the expected signature.
            Constructor<Name> ctor = Student.Name.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Student.class);
            // This forces the security manager to allow a call
            ctor.setAccessible(true);

            // the call
            Student.Name inner = ctor.newInstance(outer);
            System.out.println(inner);

            Field privateField = Class.forName("test.Student$Name").getDeclaredField("myField");
            //turning off access check with below method call
            privateField.setAccessible(true);

            System.out.println(privateField.get(inner)); // prints "5"
            privateField.set(inner, 20);
            System.out.println(privateField.get(inner)); //prints "20"
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ex : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```